# Mac Windowbuilder having issues displaying correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, user-interface, windowbuilder

I have made a basic point of sales system for a project in school and for some reason when I try to import the project on to my mac, it displays all weird and incorrectly! I have tried reinstalling eclipse as well as window builder on it, but I cant figure it out!
What it should look like:
[image]

What it ends up looking like on my mac:
[image]

this was all done using WindowBuilder for eclipse and I am stumped!

Comment: Looks like it can't find a font, for starters.
Perhaps resources available on one machine are nto available on the other. Cant really tell without looking at project structure, or code

Comment: I correclty install the fonts and got them working, just not sure why the tabs at the top are so messed up.

Comment: That is the way Mac OSX native controls display Tabs. The native controls generally don't deal with different fonts well. Since you haven't shown us any code or even said which GUI toolkit you are using it is hard to say anymore.

Comment: It is done through Swing and it is a JTabbedPane. I changed the font back to times new roman. When I set the look and feel in windowbuilder, i can get it to parse the test correctly, but when I run the code it still looks like the above picture.